# Concurrent access to a utility static method

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

We have a scenario in which several threads call a static method like the following one:

```
public static boolean isEmpty(final String s) {
    return s == null || s.length() < 1;
}
```

Could it cause a problem of inconsistence if 100 threads call it?

Comment: `s.length() == 0` is cheaper than `s.length() < 1`, and String cannot have length of less than zero.

Comment: @sudocode Or use `String.isEmpty`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No. This wont suffer from any concurrency problems.

1) The parameter you pass in is a String which is an immutable class (its value cannot be modified)

2) The method doesn't try to modify any shared state

Comment: Does it make a difference if parameter is mutable. For example if function signature is: `public static boolean isEmpty(String s) { ...}`

Comment: @broadband by removing `final` from the argument declaration you only make variable `s` mutable, not the value it holds -- values of `String` are immutable. It is essential to understand the difference. Making variable `s` mutable does not affect concurrency in any way -- any reassignments to `s` would be visible only within the method. On the other hand, if argument `s` was of some mutable type, e.g. `ArrayList`, then having `final` would not help with concurrency if `s` references some list, which is accessible from other threads.

Comment: So basically final keyword can be removed in this context, is there any sense to keep final keyword then?

Comment: Perhaps the only reason could be this: variable cannot be re-bound to reference another object, but the again you can change the value the strig points to.

Comment: @broadband a good reason to declare method arguments as `final` is to avoid accidental mistakes where a variable that is an argument is reassigned to some other value in the method body, but "thought of" as if it represents the value passed into the method call.

Answer (score 5):

The method does not access any shared state. Thus, no -- it will not cause any problems.

Answer (score 4):

No, because there are is no shared state. Even if you call this method with the same string `s`, it is still safe as `String` is immutable and thread-safe.

BTW [`StringUtils.isEmpty()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.String%29) method in Apache Commons does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

's' being the passed variable and there is nothing else defined in the method there should be no problem in case of 100 threads calling it

Answer (score 0):

So this can be thought like this, 
Whenever a thread is created, it is created with its own stack (I guess the size of the stack at the time of creation is ~2MB). So any execution that happens actually happens within the context of this thread stack. 
Any variable that is created lives in the heap but it's reference lives in the stack with the exceptions being static variables which do not live in the thread stack.

Any function call you make is actually pushed onto the thread stack, be it static or non-static. Since the complete method was pushed onto the stack, any variable creation that takes place lives within the stack (again exceptions being static variables) and only accessible to one thread.

So all the methods are thread safe until they change the state of some static variable.